# How to compose a psycopg2 dynamic SQL statement that includes functions on column names? e.g.: json_col::text

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2, dynamic-sql

I need to compose a dynamic SQL statement, which includes certain functions on column names.
E.g.: `SELECT json_col::text, SUBSTRING ( string_col ,1 , 2 ) FROM TABLE`

Since the column names are enclosed in "", I keep getting undefined column error.
What is the best way to compose a dynamic SQL with functions on column names?

Answer (score 0):

You could add the the SQL functions to your SQL statement:

```
cols = ["column1", "column2", "column3"]
table = "myTable"
query = sql.SQL(
    "select {0}::text, upper({1}), lower({2}), {3}::jsonb from {4} where id = %s").format(
        sql.Identifier("id"),
        sql.Identifier(cols[0]),
        sql.Identifier(cols[1]),
        sql.Identifier(cols[2]),
        sql.Identifier(table)
)
print(cur.mogrify(query, (240, )).decode('utf-8'))
```

Out:

```
select "id"::text, upper("column1"), lower("column2"), "column3"::jsonb from "myTable" where id = 240
```